# What are possible applications for room temperature superconductor requiring extreme presssure?

Tags: pressure, solid-mechanics, electromagnetism

At standard room pressure, the highest temperature superconductor is "the cuprate of mercury, barium, and calcium, at around 133 K" (-140 °C).

If pressure can be increased, however, the record belongs to LaH$_{10}$ at -23 °C requiring 170 GPa, or possibly [carbonaceous sulfur hydride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonaceous_sulfur_hydride) at +15 °C requiring 270 GPa.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-temperature_superconductivity)

Since -23 °C and 15 °C are commonly encountered conditions in many parts of the Earth, what possible applications might there be for a superconductor at these non-extreme temperatures, but which requires 170-270 gigapascals of pressure to operate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such applications would be extremely rare. Cooling with liquid nitrogen is easy and cheap, so using regular high temperature superconductors would almost always be preferred.

The paper claiming +15C superconductivity has actually [just been retracted](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-05294-9) by the editors of Nature, but for the sake of this question we'll assume it is true. In that case, superconductivity would only require a cool day or very good air conditioning.

To reach the necessary static pressures requires a diamond anvil, so any high-pressure superconducting component would have to be very small. One possibility might be tiny [Josephson Junctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephson_effect), but these would only really be useful technology if you could also figure out how to miniaturize the anvil to create a small sensor. In the unlikely event you could overcome the very extreme engineering challenges, these might useful for [SQUID magnetometers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQUID) and their [many applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_anvil_cell#Two_opposing_diamond_anvils), as well as [Quantum Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQUID#Uses).

There are multiple reasons why it is almost certainly impossible to scale up [diamond anvil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_anvil_cell#Two_opposing_diamond_anvils) technology to macroscopic (e.g. $\sim 1$ m) sizes:

- Metre-sized flawless diamonds are hard to come by:)
- Applying 270 GPa over an area of a square metre would require 270 GN = 28 MTf (Mega Tonne force).  The world's largest press is 10 stories tall and can only achieve $\sim 0.1$ MTf.
- Most importantly, diamond anvils fail when they become larger than about $0.1$ mm, with [one estimate for the maximum pressure](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5049720) being
  $$P_{max}\,\textrm{(GPa)} \approx \frac{2000\,\textrm{GPa}\, \mu\textrm{m}^{0.5}}{\sqrt{d}}$$
  where $d$ is the diameter of the anvil face in microns.
  The +15C result used an anvil smaller than 50 microns to achieve $270$ GPa, which is about the expected upper size limit.

Comment: Thank you. Is it technically possible to scale up a diamond anvil cell, for example, to the size of an oven, or even the length of a railway track, then squeeze the sample permanently in between this giant DAC?

Comment: @James Unfortunately it seems impossible to scale up diamond anvil cells to the size of an oven. I have extended the answer to explain why.